# Memory retained when using JToken

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jetbrains-ide, dotmemory

I am making a ASP.net core MVC call which has a JSON body which can contain 2 MBs of data, the memory of the app increases by 400MB and does not go down.

The web call has the signature:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> ReportProblem([FromBody] JToken request).
```

If I switch the above to :

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> ReportProblem([FromBody] String request)
```

I do not see a memory increase.
Each time I make the call with the JToken parameter, the memory keeps increasing by several 100MBs even though the request body contains 2MB of data.

In DotMemory I see lots of strings being used and references to LogMessageEntry.

Comment: Why are you not letting MVC convert the data into a concrete class rather then `JObject` or `string`?

Comment: Good question. This is not my code but saying that, memory usage is less if we let MVC convert the data. I am interested in why this approach (JToken) is causing so much usage of memory.

Comment: So after debugging I found that before the controller with the JToken is hit, the contents of body are printed to stdout. So it looks like as we have 2 MBs of data this is written to the console (explains the LogMessageEntry). Now, how do I disable the output?